Alternative material for evaporative cooling systems
I aim to make a better model of the traditional evaporative coolant mats made from vetiver (khus) roots. The principle of this is that it cools the surroundings by using evaporative cooling by water, hence the material has to be a very good absorbent of water, as well as durable, relatively cheap to produce and not harmful to the environment. After doing some research of my own I found out that Polyacrylic acid was a suitable material to make the improved mats with, and I came across polypropylene and polyethylene also being used in cooling systems (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378778824000720)
What material do you think could be used instead? Any thoughts on a new structural design for the mat to increase surface area for absorption?
